# al exportar datos de una consulta en php mysql el archivo csv contiene html

Tags: php, mysql

Al momento de generar el archivo CSV solo contiene HTML, ya revisé mi consulta y no hay valores nulos, ni nada por el estilo, les dejo foto del código y de antemano les agradezco mucho su tiempo.

Saludos hermanos!

**Salida del CSV**

```
CeDis   Unidades    Tipo Combustible    Proveedor   Num. Factura    Ticket-Folio    Nombre del chofer   Kilometraje Fecha consumo   Litros  Precio Unitario Subtotal    Rendimiento
<br />                                              
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>                                             
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource   object given in C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php on line <i>54</i></th></tr>                                            
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>                                             
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>                                              
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\demo.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>                                                
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0033</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>269560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.fputcsv' target='_new'>fputcsv</a>                                             
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\demo.php<b>:</b>54</td></tr>                                             
</table></font>                                             
<br />                                              
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>                                             
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource   object given in C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php on line <i>54</i></th></tr>                                            
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>                                             
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>                                              
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\demo.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>                                                
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0370</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>270640</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.fputcsv' target='_new'>fputcsv</a>                                             
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\demo.php<b>:</b>54</td></tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource   object given in C:\wamp64\www\Fuel\demo.php on line *54*

**Código**

```
<?php
 require('php/config.php');

 $fecha1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
 $fecha2 = $_POST['fecha2'];

 header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset-latin1');
 header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="reporte_combustible.csv"');

 $salida = fopen('php://output','w');

 // encabezados

 fputcsv($salida,
   array(
     'CeDis','Unidades','Tipo Combustible',
     'Proveedor','Num. Factura','Ticket-Folio',
     'Nombre del chofer','Kilometraje','Fecha consumo',
     'Litros','Precio Unitario','Subtotal','Rendimiento'
   )
 );

 $query ="SELECT 
 a.Name as Cedis,
 b.Name as Unidades,
 d.Name as Combustible,
 c.Name as Proveedor,
 e.Invoice as Factura,
 e.Ticket as TicketFolio,
 e.Driver as Conductor,
 e.Mileage as Kilometraje,
 e.Intake as FechaConsumo,
 e.Litters as Litros,
 e.UnitCost as PrecioUnitario,
 e.Subtotal as Subtotal,
 e.Efficiency as Rendimiento
 FROM branch as a
  INNER JOIN asset as b ON a.Id = b.Branch_Id
  INNER JOIN supplier as c ON  a.Id = c.Branch_Id
  INNER JOIN supply as d ON c.Id = d.Supplier_Id
  INNER JOIN data as e ON d.Id = e.Supply_Id AND b.Id = e.Asset_Id
 WHERE e.Intake BETWEEN '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2'";

 $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$query);

 while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
 {
         fputcsv($resultado, array(
         $fila['Cedis'],
         $fila['Unidades'],
         $fila['Combustible'],
         $fila['Proveedor'],
         $fila['Factura'],
         $fila['TicketFolio'],
         $fila['Conductor'],
         $fila['Kilometraje'],
         $fila['FechaConsumo'],
         $fila['Litros'],
         $fila['PrecioUnitario'],
         $fila['Subtotal'],
         $fila['Rendimiento']));

 }


?>
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Comment: es muy importante que el codigo este como texto en la pregunta y no como imagen. Es dificil de ver y en celulares directamente no se ve. Cambia eso por favor. mira [ask]

Comment: copia y pega el error que te da, así es más fácil que te podamos ayudar en vez de imagenes.

Comment: Listo hermano, una disculpa, En si no es un error, si no que me imprime HTML como se ve en la primera imagen. Debería importar el resultado que serían 2 filas

Comment: el error lo dice todo: `fputcsv($resultado, array(` debería ser `fputcsv($salida, array(` . en vez del stream de salida le estas pasando el objeto msqli

Comment: Oh lo siento, Muchas gracias hermano me salvaste la vida!, soy nuevo en esto de programación, muchas gracias!